# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when running python in background mode and calling region_3d.update()

Tags: python, scripting, uv, 3d-view

I need to run a python script in background mode, without GUI.
The purpose is to unwrap uv from top view of some loaded object & texture.
To do that, I use the `bpy.ops.uv.project_from_view` operation after setting the view to *Top*.
As I saw in the forums, I need to run `region_3d.update()` between those calls so that the top view operation take effect, and calling this function causes `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.

Here's a sample of the code to reproduce the failure:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':                
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area, region=region, edit_object=bpy.context.edit_object):
                    bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='TOP')
                    area.spaces[0].region_3d.update() # <<< blender crashes here <<<
                    bpy.ops.uv.project_from_view(orthographic=True, camera_bounds=False,
                                                 correct_aspect=True,
                                                 scale_to_bounds=True)
                break
```

Note that running this code while Blender is open, **works perfectly**, however, when I run it in background mode it crashes:

```
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3\blender.exe" untitled.blend --background --python crash_repro.py
```

*untitled.blend* is a dummy blender file with cube.

The crash report:

```
# Blender 3.3.0, Commit date: 2022-09-06 15:39, Hash 0759f671ce1f

# backtrace
Exception Record:

ExceptionCode         : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Exception Address     : 0x00007FF6F84E3B72
Exception Module      : blender.exe
Exception Flags       : 0x00000000
Exception Parameters  : 0x2
    Parameters[0] : 0x0000000000000000
    Parameters[1] : 0x0000000000000018


Stack trace:
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F84E3B40  GPU_matrix_ortho_set
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F427AB20  view3d_winmatrix_set
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F427CFF0  ED_view3d_update_viewmat
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F395DD40  rna_RegionView3D_update
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F393AAD0  RNA_function_call
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F3A69840  pyrna_func_call
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851C19DD0  PyObject_MakeTpCall
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D2F000  PyEval_GetFuncDesc
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D288F0  PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D288F0  PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D28680  PyEval_EvalCode
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D197E0  PyWarnings_Init
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851C5E1C0  PyCFunction_GetFlags
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D26D50  PyOS_URandomNonblock
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D2F000  PyEval_GetFuncDesc
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D288F0  PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851D288F0  PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851DA0410  PyRun_FileExFlags
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851DA0410  PyRun_FileExFlags
python310.dll       :0x00007FF851DA0270  PyRun_StringFlags
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F3A5DAB0  python_script_exec
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F3A5D680  BPY_run_filepath
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F27B3420  arg_handle_python_file_run
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F869A370  BLI_args_parse
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F27B12A0  main
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F88D28B0  __scrt_common_main_seh
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Threads:
Thread : 0000186c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED07720  ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC76730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00008a00
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED07720  ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC76730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00008794
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED07720  ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC76730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00002ee8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00005998
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00008ce8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000051ec
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00005ea0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000046e4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00007990
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00007100
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00006b1c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00002cc8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00008220
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 0000142c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 0000814c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00008740
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00005cf0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000048f8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00006cbc
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00006ce4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00007c60
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00008638
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465F30  IlmThread_3_1::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F9465740  IlmThread_3_1::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6F2973A50  std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl usdBlender__pxrReserved__::HdRenderThread::*)(void) _
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00006dd0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED07720  ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC76730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00004058
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED07720  ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC76730  EtwNotificationRegister
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000088a0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFA405AD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFA405AD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00000c5c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFA405AD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFA405AD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00004d9c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFA405AD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFA405AD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00008a08
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4ED03BF0  ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFA4C4724C0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFA405AD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
tbb.dll             :0x00007FFA405AD800  tbb::thread_bound_filter::try_process_item
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFA4C9B6BB0  recalloc
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFA4CC45540  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFA4EC64830  RtlUserThreadStart


Loaded Modules :
0x00007FF6F2640000 3.3.0.0              blender.exe C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3\blender.pdb 
0x00007FFA4EC60000 10.0.22000.918       ntdll.dll  
0x00007FFA4CC30000 10.0.22000.1219      KERNEL32.DLL  
0x00007FFA4C430000 10.0.22000.1165      KERNELBASE.dll  
0x00007FFA4E850000 10.0.22000.1         WS2_32.dll  
0x00007FFA4DA60000 10.0.22000.675       RPCRT4.dll  
0x00007FFA4E470000 10.0.22000.1165      USER32.dll  
0x00007FFA4CAB0000 10.0.22000.1219      win32u.dll  
0x00007FFA4D580000 10.0.22000.832       GDI32.dll  
0x00007FFA4C310000 10.0.22000.1098      gdi32full.dll  
0x00007FFA4C130000 10.0.22000.1         msvcp_win.dll  
0x00007FFA4C990000 10.0.22000.1         ucrtbase.dll  
0x00007FFA4EB70000 10.0.22000.1098      ADVAPI32.dll  
0x00007FFA4D9B0000 7.0.22000.1          msvcrt.dll  
0x00007FFA4E200000 10.0.22000.708       sechost.dll  
0x00007FFA4CCF0000 10.0.22000.1165      SHELL32.dll  
0x00007FFA4D4C0000 10.0.22000.1         SHLWAPI.dll  
0x00007FFA4E6B0000 10.0.22000.120       ole32.dll  
0x00007FFA4D630000 10.0.22000.1165      combase.dll  
0x00007FFA496D0000 10.0.22000.1         dbghelp.dll  
0x00007FFA405A0000                      tbb.dll  
0x00007FFA4EA70000 10.0.22000.1         PSAPI.DLL  
0x00007FFA4E0B0000 10.0.22000.613       shcore.dll  
0x00007FFA4D540000 10.0.22000.1165      IMM32.dll  
0x00007FFA32070000                      tbbmalloc.dll  
0x00007FF9DF070000 10.0.22000.1042      OPENGL32.dll  
0x00007FF8544E0000 9.0.0.0              openvdb.dll  
0x00007FF851FE0000 59.18.100.0          avcodec-59.dll  
0x00007FFA32140000 59.4.100.0           avdevice-59.dll  
0x00007FFA4CB50000 10.0.22000.1         OLEAUT32.dll  
0x00007FF99B470000 59.16.100.0          avformat-59.dll  
0x00007FFA30270000 6.4.100.0            swscale-6.dll  
0x00007FF9FE3D0000 1.21.1.0             OpenAL32.dll  
0x00007FF9A6950000 57.17.100.0          avutil-57.dll  
0x0000000070440000 1.0.28.0             libsndfile-1.dll  
0x000000006ACC0000                      libgmp-10.dll  
0x00007FFA425E0000                      libgmpxx.dll  
0x00007FF9A85B0000 2.0.20.0             SDL2.dll  
0x00007FFA4DB80000 10.0.22000.469       SETUPAPI.dll  
0x00007FF851B10000 3.10.2150.1013       python310.dll  
0x00007FFA4BE00000 10.0.22000.1         CFGMGR32.dll  
0x00007FFA4BB10000 10.0.22000.1         bcrypt.dll  
0x00007FFA425D0000                      tbbmalloc_proxy.dll  
0x00007FFA2FEE0000 10.0.22000.1165      AVIFIL32.dll  
0x00007FFA30F40000 6.10.22000.120       COMCTL32.dll  
0x00007FFA1E8D0000 14.29.30139.0        MSVCP140.dll  
0x00007FFA43010000 10.0.22000.1         VERSION.dll  
0x00007FFA413D0000 14.29.30139.0        VCRUNTIME140.dll  
0x00007FFA499E0000 10.0.22000.41        dwmapi.dll  
0x00007FFA41440000 14.29.30139.0        VCRUNTIME140_1.dll  
0x00007FFA1D920000 10.0.22000.1042      GLU32.dll  
0x00007FFA3FAC0000 10.0.22000.1165      AVICAP32.dll  
0x00007FFA30070000 10.0.22000.675       Secur32.dll  
0x00007FFA43B70000 10.0.22000.1         WINMM.dll  
0x00007FFA3F090000 10.0.22000.1165      MSVFW32.dll  
0x00007FFA427C0000 10.0.22000.1         MSACM32.dll  
0x0000000070680000                      libfftw3-3.dll  
0x00007FFA46C90000 10.0.22000.653       dxcore.dll  
0x00007FFA4B530000 10.0.22000.1098      SSPICLI.DLL  
0x00007FFA22370000 4.3.100.0            swresample-4.dll  
0x00007FFA4B2A0000 10.0.22000.71        kernel.appcore.dll  
0x00007FFA4A1F0000 10.0.22000.1165      windows.storage.dll  
0x00007FFA4A080000 10.0.22000.1165      wintypes.dll  
0x00007FFA4C060000 10.0.22000.1         profapi.dll  
0x00007FFA4C290000 10.0.22000.778       bcryptPrimitives.dll  
0x00007FFA4DFF0000 2001.12.10941.16384  clbcatq.dll  
0x00007FFA41070000 10.0.22000.1042      MMDevApi.dll  
0x00007FFA4BE50000 10.0.22000.1         DEVOBJ.dll  
0x00007FFA34690000 10.0.22000.708       AUDIOSES.DLL  
0x00007FFA4AA70000 10.0.22000.1         powrprof.dll  
0x00007FFA4AB70000 10.0.22000.1         UMPDC.dll  
0x00007FFA4B990000 10.0.22000.1         CRYPTSP.dll  
0x00007FFA4B200000 10.0.22000.282       rsaenh.dll  
0x00007FFA4B980000 10.0.22000.1         CRYPTBASE.dll  

# Python backtrace
  File "C:\Users\shama\OneDrive\Desktop\crash_repro.py.txt", line 13 in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1 in <module>
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem in MacOs and blender 3.6.1 and Ubuntu with version 2.79.

Answer (score 1):

As @Iván found out in a [similar post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301490/why-i-need-to-run-my-script-twice-to-get-it-to-work), there is a [bug report](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/102738) which states that this is not considered a bug, quote:

> I don't consider this a bug. Calling an operator from background can be expected to lead to these issues. As operators might require the GPU and the GPU is only available when running with UI. The region 3d is an editor structure and is expected to be run with UI.