# Why I need to run my script twice to get it to work?

Tags: python, scripting

Basically I am trying to write a script to

1. create a square image
2. add some objects to it
3. get the positions of the objects in frame coordinates of the objects.

There is a second part of the script in which I render the frame and also save the positions of the objects in a pickle file but I am not including it to make the script shorter.

The idea is that then I am going to create some bounding boxes to the objects in python and use them for other purposes. So I need to be able to render the image and export object locations in frame coordinates.

If I open the script from blender, the first time I run it it has an error, but the second time I run it it works fine and I get these values

```
**cube
[0.0035274855948945524, 0.24358138840914842, 0.7366971959744029, 0.9738736891060572]
**********************
**sphere
[0.43452719267736106, 0.5654728073226389, 0.43452716000590824, 0.5654728399940917]
**********************
```

which are the correct one.

If I run the script from the command line it fails because `view3d_camera_border` is not working as expected and I get the same error as when I run the script from the GUI:

```bash
blender -b --python test_camera_blender.py
```

So it looks that I have some missing/wrong initial config in the file that after I run it two times it is fixed. I have been tying to debug the whole thing but I am not able to make it work.
Any ideas which configuration I am missing?

Script:

````py
"""
Some usefuleful referenes:
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55300/how-can-i-get-the-x-y-location-of-an-object-at-each-frame-of-animation
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237428/get-pixel-coords-for-vertex-in-viewport
- https://gist.github.com/simonecesano/2cefcfac7485939a18249c4672e4a5ff
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6377/coordinates-of-corners-of-camera-view-border
"""

import bpy
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Vector
import bmesh
import bpy_extras

# make the output dimensions square 1920x1920
create_objects = True
im_size = 1920


def to_rad(deg):
    return deg * np.pi / 180


def delete_all_objects():
    """
    Deletes all objects in the current scene
    """
    deleteListObjects = [
        "MESH",
        "CURVE",
        "SURFACE",
        "META",
        "FONT",
        "HAIR",
        "POINTCLOUD",
        "VOLUME",
        "GPENCIL",
        "ARMATURE",
        "LATTICE",
        "EMPTY",
        "LIGHT",
        "LIGHT_PROBE",
        "CAMERA",
        "SPEAKER",
    ]

    # Select all objects in the scene to be deleted:

    for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        for i in deleteListObjects:
            if o.type == i:
                o.select_set(False)
            else:
                o.select_set(True)
    # Deletes all selected objects in the scene:

    bpy.ops.object.delete()


def toggle_camera(context):
    for area in context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
            space = area.spaces.active
            r3d = space.region_3d
            plane_no = r3d.view_rotation @ Vector((0, 0, -1))
            region = area.regions[-1]
            area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
            area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_camera_offset = (0,0)
            area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_camera_zoom = -1000
            break
    else:
        assert False, "Requires a $D view"
    return region, r3d, area


def region_3d(context):
    for area in context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
            space = area.spaces.active
            r3d = space.region_3d
            plane_no = r3d.view_rotation @ Vector((0, 0, -1))
            region = area.regions[-1]
            break
    else:
        assert False, "Requires a $D view"
    return region, r3d, area


def vertex_positions_2d(obj, region, r3d):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
    bm.transform(obj.matrix_world)

    v_2d_co = np.array(
        [
            bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, r3d, v.co)
            for v in bm.verts
        ]
    )
    return v_2d_co


def view3d_camera_border(scene, region, r3d):
    obj = scene.camera
    cam = obj.data
    frame = cam.view_frame(scene=scene)
    print("**cam frame")
    for f in frame:
        print(f)
    # move into object space
    frame = [obj.matrix_world @ v for v in frame]
    print("**cam frame world debug")
    for f in frame:
        print(f)
    # move into pixel space
    frame_px = [
        bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, r3d, v, default='NOOTTT') for v in frame
    ]
    print("**frame_px debug")
    for f in frame_px:
        print(f)
    return frame_px


def rescale_2d_to_cam(xy, cbounds):
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = cbounds
    x, y = xy
    x = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
    y = (y - y_min) / (y_max - y_min)
    return list((x, y))


def get_min_max_from_list(l):
    min_x = np.min([v[0] for v in l])
    max_x = np.max([v[0] for v in l])
    min_y = np.min([v[1] for v in l])
    max_y = np.max([v[1] for v in l])
    return [min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y]


def to_camera_view(scene, cam, obj):
    _c = []
    for vert in obj.data.vertices: 
        # local to global coordinates
        co = obj.matrix_world @ vert.co
        coords2d = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, co)
        # print("coords2d: {},{}".format(coords2d.x, coords2d.y))
        _c.append(coords2d)
    return _c


def create_objects_func():
    # add cube
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(2, -3.9, 7.2), rotation=(0, to_rad(45), 0))
    cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
    cube.name = "cube"

    # Make a sphere at the origin named 'sphere'
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
    sphere = bpy.data.objects["Sphere"]
    sphere.name = "sphere"

    ## Add a camera facing the cube from 45 top angle
    bpy.ops.object.camera_add(
        location=(15, 0, 15), rotation=(to_rad(45), 0, to_rad(90))
    )
    camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
    camera.name = "camera"

    ## Add a light source
    bpy.ops.object.light_add(
        type="SUN", location=(25, 0, 25), rotation=(0, to_rad(28), to_rad(20))
    )
    lamp = bpy.data.objects["Sun"]
    lamp.name = "sun"
    lamp.data.energy = 1


def main():
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        print(scene)
        scene.render.resolution_x = im_size
        scene.render.resolution_y = im_size

    context = bpy.context
    scene = context.scene
    toggle_camera(context)

    print("______________________")
    print('**debug resolution', scene.render.resolution_x, scene.render.resolution_y)
    

    region, r3d, area = region_3d(context)
    
    
    if create_objects:
        delete_all_objects()
        create_objects_func()
        scene.camera = bpy.data.objects["camera"]

    area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
    area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_camera_offset = (0,0)
    area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_camera_zoom = -1000

    # get the cube position in world coordinates
    cube = bpy.data.objects["cube"]
    loc, rot, scale = cube.matrix_world.decompose()
    print("**cube world coords")
    print("**loc", loc)

    # Get info of objects
    print("**DEBUG", region, r3d)
    frame_px = view3d_camera_border(scene, region, r3d)
    print("**frame_px", frame_px)

    cam_min_x = np.min([v[0] for v in frame_px])
    cam_max_x = np.max([v[0] for v in frame_px])
    cam_min_y = np.min([v[1] for v in frame_px])
    cam_max_y = np.max([v[1] for v in frame_px])
    cam_bounds = [cam_min_x, cam_max_x, cam_min_y, cam_max_y]
    print("**camera bounds", cam_bounds)

    print(region, r3d)
    final_positions = {}

    for name in ['cube', 'sphere']:
        
        positions = vertex_positions_2d(bpy.data.objects[name], region, r3d)
        positions_scaled = [rescale_2d_to_cam(xy, cam_bounds) for xy in positions]
        print(f"**{name} ")
        print(get_min_max_from_list(positions_scaled))
        final_positions[name] = get_min_max_from_list(positions_scaled)
        
        
        print("**********************")
    
    print("______________________")


main()

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error does not pop up for the first time only, you can provoke it also when running the script multiple times. After running the script, move into the sphere (such that you are inside) and run the script again. This will tigger the error again.

The reason is that, as you noticed, `view3d_camera_border` is not working correctly, but actually it does. Within that method you're calling

```
bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, r3d, v, default='NOOTTT') for v in frame
```

and when inspecting the debug prints you should notice there are `NOOTTT` values in `frame_px` causing the error:

> ... ufunc 'minimum' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> None

As the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html#bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d) state for `location_3d_to_region_2d`:

> default – Return this value if coord is behind the origin of a perspective view.

This gives you the clue that something with the camera view from the 3D region is wrong. If you run the script for the second time it works because the scene camera's view and the region's view *do match accidently*. And thats why you can provoke the error again if you're moving the region's camera to a position where "coord is behind the origin of a perspective view".

What you need to do is to update the region after you changed the the view data so you get the correct camera data to work with. You have two places in code where you do:

```
area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_camera_offset = (0,0)
area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_camera_zoom = -1000
```

one in `def toggle_camera` and one in `def main` (you should use `toggle_camera` there too). Change that to:

```
area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_camera_offset = (0,0)
area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_camera_zoom = -1000
area.spaces[0].region_3d.update()    # <-- here
```

and it works like desired.

Comment: Hmmm, definitely something changed with this, but you are going to see that the print of the `**cube` and `**sphere` coordinates are sill different the first and second time I run the script. I am not obtaining the `NOOTTT`, so that is good. If I run the script from command line I get a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Sorry my bad, coordinates are correct only when I run from the GUI, from the command line I get the segmentation fault error.

Comment: I tried it on two different computers with different OS and blender versions and both of them have segmentation error problem. It is when executing the `area.spaces[0].region_3d.update()` line.

Comment: @Iván can confirm. Tbh i didn't checked the command line version. There is another post with exactly the same problem, unfortunately unanswered https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279152/exception-access-violation-when-running-python-in-background-mode-and-calling-re Maybe a bug?

Comment: Hmm, :( . Actually I need to run this script in the command line version. There is no workaround for this, right?
I am having problems with blender 2.79 and 3.6.1.

Comment: Apparently it is not a bug... https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/102738

Comment: Oh wow well.. at least this fits with the crash logs, last call is a `GPU_matrix_..._set`. If you run the cmdline without `-b` it works. Maybe that's acceptable for you to have Blender open (maybe minimized)?

Comment: I need to run 100k iterations of a similar script in a server to generate a dataset. So having the GUI is not an option :( .

Comment: :( Looks like you need to implement your own version of `region_3d.update()` calculating the updated matrices for `region_3d`.

Comment: FWIW here's the lines in the source code. https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/8e843920d473ac83a70bddfd3bfe0c1bcd6b5e42/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_draw.cc#L105-L114 @Iván If you know your way around c++ or can find / hire someone to navigate it you might be able to create your own logic there. Expect complicated and heavy matricial calculations though.